# NodeJs, handle expiration date for user votes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, timeout, setinterval

I'm currently working on a app. This also includes some kind of group chats. 
The users inside can make multiple votes, for example for kicking someone. The votes are all valid for 1 week. If all other users submit their opinion the vote gets deleted.So far so good.

I also want a logic, which deletes the vote automatically if it's expired.
So far I got the idea to store the expiration dates for the votes inside a database(MongoDB), sorted by their timestamp of expiration.
In NodeJs I'm always loading the vote with the smallest expiration date from the database.
Then I check how much time is left by subtracting the vote expiration date from the current Date

```
Date.now() - voteTmp;
```

Then I can set a timeout, which calls a function to delete the vote and automatically starts a new timeout for the next vote. Is it a problem to set a timeout with such a big number of seconds?

Do you have any better ideas?
Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

The [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js) event loop is explained [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#what-is-the-event-loop):

[image: simplified overview of the event loop's order of operations]

> when the event loop enters a given phase, it will perform any operations specific to that phase, then execute callbacks in that phase's queue until the queue has been exhausted or the maximum number of callbacks has executed.

---

On each iteration, the event loop checks for scheduled timers that satisfy the specified thresholds (delays) and executes their callbacks. Thus, the magnitude of delays for registered timers **shouldn't** matter.

However, in your scenario, there's a chance that you might accidentally register redundant or invalid timers (possibly after recovering from a crash). [**MongoDB** supports (automatic) data expiration](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/). You can instruct MongoDB to delete documents after a specified number of seconds has passed. That seems close enough to what you want to do.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I think i will have to stick with the first option, with the timeouts, because I need to know when and which vote gets deleted. I wouldn't know that if mongodb just deletes my votes. Unfortunatelyy I can't use a change Stream on the collection because I don't have a replica set.